# I can't use negative numbers for height and width in a box, fillRect, drawImage, etc

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, rotation, negative-number

I am making a 3d game and to make a cube, an image needed to rotate more than to it's 0 point:[image: showing my explanation, you need to understand :(]

the last image is like seeing the back of the image as it was transparent. It has rotated round......
I tried this, I think it should work, or didn't the javascript developers think of it? :

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(100, 100, -100, - 100);
```

Here is my 3d thingy for those who are interested : [Just for fun, try to use it also with sphere, in your notepad](https://jsfiddle.net/zz94snmu/)

Comment: if it's really 3D, have you considered WebGL ?

Comment: I want to make hard, and not learn another language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using negative widths, you can use negative scale factors, e.g.  if you use `ctx.scale(-1, 1)` then all of your coordinates will draw from right to left instead of left to right.

See https://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/eqyqmdk3/ for a demo.

Comment: Gracias xD i think i can do it now